# Change Text based on time with Javascript

Tags: javascript, time

Right now I'm pulling in the current time in the span `#time`, and would like to add custom messages into `#officehours` based on the time, but am having trouble getting them to play nicely with each other.

```js
//Timestamp
function getTimeCurrentTime() {
   let time = new Date();
   return time.toLocaleString('en-US').split(',')[1];
}

function updateCurrentTime() {
   let timeNode = document.getElementById('time');
   timeNode.innerHTML = getTimeCurrentTime();
}

setInterval(updateCurrentTime, 1000);

function officeHours() {
  var myDate = new Date();
  var hrs = myDate.getHours();

  var greet;

  if (hrs < 12)
      greet = 'Good Morning';
  else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17)
      greet = 'Good Afternoon';
  else if (hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24)
      greet = 'Good Evening';

      document.getElementById('officehours').innerHTML = greet;
}
```

```html
<div class="timecontainer">
      <span>Office Hours:</span><br>
      <span>M-F, 9:00-5:00</span><br>
      <span>Currently:</span><span id="time"></span><br>
      <span>We Are:</span><span id="officehours"></span>
   </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: Here was my first try: 

'function officeHours() {
  var myDate = new Date();
  var hrs = myDate.getHours();

  var officeHours;

  if (hrs < 12)
      greet = 'Good Morning';
  else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17)
      greet = 'Good Afternoon';
  else if (hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24)
      greet = 'Good Evening';

  document.getElementById('officehours').innerHTML =
      officeHours;
}'

but it doesn't output anything into the span.

Comment: Please include relevant code as an edit to the question itself.  In this case it's particularly useful to edit it into the runnable code snippet to provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem so we can observe specifically what is happening.

Comment: Understood @David , and fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the function.

You've defined a function called `updateCurrentTime`:

```
function updateCurrentTime() {
  //...
}
```

And you call it at 1-second intervals:

```
setInterval(updateCurrentTime, 1000);
```

You've also defined a function called `officeHours`:

```
function officeHours() {
  //...
}
```

But you never call it.  In order to execute a function, you have to invoke it.  Presumably in this case the intent is to invoke it from the `updateCurrentTime` function.  For example:

```
function updateCurrentTime() {
  let timeNode = document.getElementById('time');
  timeNode.innerHTML = getTimeCurrentTime();
  officeHours();
}
```